# Djangobooks search bar errors Chapter 7

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm not sure why this is occurring between my two search functions.

here is my first search function

```
    def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
    q = request.GET['q']
    books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains = q)
    return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'books': books, 'query': q})
    else:
    return render_to_response('search_form.html', {'error': True})
```

With this function, when I enter

```
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/
```

into my browser, what would display is a search bar and a message that I created. Also when I press the search button, the link would automatically update to

```
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=
```

However for the 2nd version of my search function

```
    def search(request):
        error = False
        if 'q' in request.GET['q']:
            q = request.GET['q']
            if not q:
             error = True
            else:
             books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains = q)
             return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'books': books, 'query': q})
    return render_to_response('search_form.html',{'error':error})
```

If I were to enter

```
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/
```

into my browser, I would get

```
    Exception Type:      MultiValueDictKeyError
    Exception Value:    "Key 'q' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
```

If I were to manually make the link in the browser

```
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=
```

the error message would disappear but if I were to performance searches, all I would get is a search bar that does nothing except update the link to whatever I input into the search bar and ran a search.

```
    EX: searched for eggs --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=eggs
```

Here are my HTML files

search_results.html

```
    <p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

    {% if books %}
        <p>Found {{ books|length }} book{{ books|pluralize }}.</p>
        <ul>
            {% for book in books %}
            <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No books matched your search criteria.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

search_form.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if error %}
            <p style = "color: red;">Please submit a search term.</P>
        {% endif %}
        <form action = "/search/" method = "get">
            <input type = "text" name = "q">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Search">
        </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

ANY HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You type :

```
if 'q' in request.GET['q']:
```

and you should type :

```
if 'q' in request.GET:
```

It fails because you try to access to a missing item.
You also can do :

```
if request.GET.get('q', False):
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Zulu said, you can use the `get()` method belonging to dictionaries to tidy up the code a little bit:

```
def search(request):

    query = request.GET.get("q", None)

    if query:
        books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains = query)
        return render_to_response("search_results.html", {"books": books, "query": query})

    # if we're here, it's because `query` is None
    return render_to_response("search_form.html", {"error": True})
```